# How to close Angular auxiliary route automatically after every primary route change

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-router

I have a sidebar with Auxiliary routes, and I don't want to show the sidebar paths in the URL. So I use the `skipLocationChange`.
But Angular will show the sidebar's route in the URL after every primary route change with `routerLink`.

I don't want to change every `routerLink`, and I don't want to add `outletName: null` for every named outlet in the `routerLink` manually.

Is there a solution to automatically close the sidebar after every primary route change or permanently hide the named outlet's path in the URL?